# No bars with chinmaymk angular-charts

Tags: angularjs, charts, angularjs-directive

I am trying to use chinmaymk.github.io angular-charts from  https://github.com/chinmaymk/angular-charts.

I have copied code from the plnkr example: http://plnkr.co/edit/T9J7bz?p=preview
`<div data-ac-chart="'bar'" data-ac-data="data" data-ac-config="config" class="chart"></div>`

However I don't get any bars on the chart. I can see the legend, horizontal and vertical axis, just no bars.
The data is set up in the controller.

My index.html file has the following imports:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular-cookies.js"></script>
<script src="~/App/Vendor/Scripts/d3/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/App/Vendor/Scripts/angular-charts-0.2.0/dist/angular-charts.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/App/app.js"></script>
```

There are other imports, however I think these are the relevant ones.

My controller and view follow the example above but still I don't see the actual bars.
I don't get any errors in the console.

Any ideas? I am happy to post more code if it would help...

Comment: The script tags are correctly formatted and valid html in my code, I am not sure how to escape the html so that it displays in SO.

Comment: It is version 3.4.9 of the d3 library. I am also using bootstrap 3, if that has any relevance

Comment: Here is the graph, without the bars: http://financialtrackr.azurewebsites.net/#/

Comment: can you create a plnkr which reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This was solved by removing a script tag referencing a local date.js file. I could not reproduce the error when using: `<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datejs/1.0/date.min.js"></script>`.

It might have been a corrupt date.js file on my side...